# Iphone App that can open other apps? How

Tags: ios, iphone

There is an App out there that can 'intercept' pictures from snapchat. I'm not sure what low level witch craft they are using to accomplish this, but I want to learn more about how to do it and I don't know what to search!

Can someone please help me? This is the app I am referring to:
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/snapbox-save-snapchat-snaps/id727651340?mt=8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just read the app description you are referring, and I don't think **intercept** could be the right word to use. You will need to read more about [Terms of Service](https://www.snapchat.com/terms) from SnapShat and probably try to read if they provide any official api so you can use it.

What this app does, is actually consuming in someway the posts you are receiving and then saving it to your iPhone. That's not a hard task tough.

Comment: ohhhh. Thank you very much for your response. So it sounds like this app takes advantage of Snapchat's API? (nothing more). So assuming that Snapchat sends a data object, (like a picture), to this other app it can save it?

Comment: @GalenLansbury Yes, just the api. And yes, if they send any picture information you can save it into your device.

Comment: Thank you very much. You saved me a lot of time. I thought that maybe it had something to do with injecting into different processes or something crazy like that.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you're providing your snapchat login to this app and they're using it to pretend they're you to communicate with Snapchat.

No actual "intercepting" is happening, and the app likely works without Snapchat installed.

see: http://blog.snapchat.com/post/99998266095/third-party-applications-and-the-snapchat-api

Comment: ohhhh. Thank you very much for your response. So it sounds like this app takes advantage of Snapchat's API? (nothing more). So assuming that Snapchat sends a data object, (like a picture), to this other app it can save it?